# Image Editing iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `AssetPicker` image library. My query is, I capture image portrait mode and display image my image view and flip image horizontal to image is starch and not properly showing ..

```
         - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
           {
          __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

           if (CFStringCompare((CFStringRef) [info   object ForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType], kUTTypeImage, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
             {
           if(self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex ==1 && self.segmentedControl.hidden == NO)
           {
             self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
            [self changeAssetType:YES endBlock:^{
            _strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
             UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:strongSelf  name:ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification object:nil];
            [strongSelf.assetsLibrary   writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image.CGImage metadata:info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self saveAssetsAction:assetURL error:error           isPhoto:YES];
                 });
                 DLog(@"writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum");
                }];

             }];

       }
            else
            {
           UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification object:nil];
        [self.assetsLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image.CGImage metadata:info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
            __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [strongSelf saveAssetsAction:assetURL error:error isPhoto:YES];
            });
            DLog(@"writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum");
        }];
          }
       }
         else 
           {
           if(self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex ==0 && self.segmentedControl.hidden == NO)
          {
            self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
            [self changeAssetType:NO endBlock:^{
             __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;

             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:strongSelf name:ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification object:nil];
             [strongSelf.assetsLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                DLog(@"assetURL %@",assetURL);
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self saveAssetsAction:assetURL error:error isPhoto:NO];
                  });
              }];

          }];
        }
              else
       {
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification object:nil];
          [self.assetsLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self saveAssetsAction:assetURL error:error isPhoto:NO];
            });

        }];

    }
}

     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];


}
```

flip image horizontally is my code

```
    UIImage *sourceImage = originalimg;

    CIImage *coreImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage.CGImage];

     UIImage *imgMirror = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:coreImage scale:sourceImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];

     CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, originalimg.size.width, originalimg.size.height);

      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);

    [imgMirror drawInRect:rect];

    originalimg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    imgview2.image = originalimg;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Your question/working is quite unclear... Are you saying that your image gets stretched and thats what is wrong?

Comment: you should have enough reputation points now to upload an image showing the failure. We have no idea what you need...

Answer (score 0):

Exchange Value of image width with image height.

`CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, originalimg.size.height, originalimg.size.width);`

> Your Image is stretched because if your are picking an image with
>   dimension 400X800 (Portrait mode) then your new fliped image is also
>   created with 400X800 dimension instead of 800X400.